# Cordova SQL - Select data from multiple table

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I have a few tables in my SQLite database and each of them have a foreign key that tie each other.

Lets say the structure are like:

```
Person
=========
Id
Name

Income
=========
IncomeId
PersonId
Income

Contact
=========
ContactId
PersonId
ContactName
```

The `PersonId` in both income and contact table are foreign key to the Person table.

Now when i want to query out the data from all the tables, first i select from `Person`, then in the callback, i will loop through the data, and select from `Income` and `Contact` for each of the record. I can't do a join select as the data are not mandatory, i.e. for a Person it might have income but not contact, or vice versa.

However when i try to run through the loop, i found that the result is always the last instance of the data. After some googling the issue seems to be that i need to use Closure.

I tried to implement it but is having a hard time, currently my code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){

    var profile= results.rows.item(i);
    var IdAir = profile["IdAir"];
    console.log('processing AIR Id: ' + IdAir);

    function queryIncomeSuccess(tx,incomeAirResult, currentLoop){
        var lenIncomeAir = incomeAirResult.rows.length;
        var incomeAIR = {};
        if(lenIncomeAir > 0){
            incomeAIR = incomeAirResult.rows.item(0);
        }else{
            incomeAIR = null;
        }

            if(currentLoop == len - 1)
        {
               profile["Income"] = incomeAIR ; 
           airJson[airJson.length] = profile;
            }

    };
    function queryIncome(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Income WHERE IdAir = ?", 
                [IdAir], function(resultSet){
                    queryIncomeSuccess(tx,resultSet,i);
                  }, errorCB);
    };
    db.transaction(queryIncome, errorCB);

}
```

Is there any guide for multiple select for Cordova? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with JOIN statement? Why you do not use it?

Comment: can't join because there's actually 3 layers of data and the first layer need to be process first before coming to the loop above. Anyway i found out how to use closure for my case above, probably will post an answer later on. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am able to get this done by using nested function and closure.

The thing to note is that, the closure need to apply at the db.transaction function, rather than on the success callback only.

Code structure used:

```
//inside for loop of first select result
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){

   function buildSuccessCallback(current,profile){
      return function(tx, result){
         querySuccess(tx, result,current,profile);
      };
   }

   function querySuccess(tx,result,currentIdx,profile){
      //...perform logic

      console.log('currentIdx: ' + currentIdx); //returning the correct value
      console.log('current Id: ' + profile["IdAir"]); //returning the correct Id
   }

   db.transaction((function(i,profile){
      return function(tx){
         tx.executeSql(mySQL, [profile["IdAir"]], buildSuccessCallback(i,profile), errorCB);
      };
   })(i,profile), errorCB);
}
```

Thanks.